# Remove Content of String With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pulling news/sports/tech articles from an API and populating the articles in my webpage. The problem here is that in many of my articles I keep getting a string of text that contains javascript.

Example, snippets from some of our articles:

```
 Viewers can also choose to ignore the teaser that appears, and it will go away allowing you to watch the video uninterrupted. /* */ if (ads.isMobile()) { (function(window,$){ window.TechCrunch.loader.on('tc_ads_wrapper_omniture', function(){ if ( !window.ads.isAdPageSet ){ if ( typeof window.adSetAdURL == 'function' ) { window.adSetAdURL('/wp-content/themes/vip/techcrunch-2013/_uac/adpage.html'); window.ads.isAdPageSet = true; } } window.htmlAdWH('348-14-15-135e', "300", "115", 'f', 'adsDivafa83e683e'); }); }(this,this.jQuery)); } /* */ YouTube notes that over time, the plan is to not only help creators provide this enriched experience to viewers,
```

another article:

```
Their best strategy, I believe, is to communicate emotions rather than specific nouns and verbs. /* */ if (ads.isMobile()) { (function(window,$){ window.TechCrunch.loader.on('tc_ads_wrapper_omniture', function(){ if ( !window.ads.isAdPageSet ){ if ( typeof window.adSetAdURL == 'function' ) { window.adSetAdURL('/wp-content/themes/vip/techcrunch-2013/_uac/adpage.html'); window.ads.isAdPageSet = true; } } window.htmlAdWH('348-14-15-135e', "300", "115", 'f', 'adsDiv186350d01b'); }); }(this,this.jQuery)); } /* */ In a classic perceptual psychology experiment, pairs of strangers were asked to communicate emotions through touch alone. The “encoder” was given one of 12 different emotions, then touched the “decoder’s” forearm through a curtain.
```

and another:

```
“We’re known for digital content advertising, but close to 40% of our business has been mobile commerce for quite some time, in areas like user acquisition and monetization outside of the basic sales transaction.” /* */ if (ads.isMobile()) { (function(window,$){ window.TechCrunch.loader.on('tc_ads_wrapper_omniture', function(){ if ( !window.ads.isAdPageSet ){ if ( typeof window.adSetAdURL == 'function' ) { window.adSetAdURL('/wp-content/themes/vip/techcrunch-2013/_uac/adpage.html'); window.ads.isAdPageSet = true; } } window.htmlAdWH('348-14-15-135e', "300", "115", 'f', 'adsDivafa83e683e'); }); }(this,this.jQuery)); } /* */ The strategic nature of the investment from Market Tech was part of the reason why Lin said Glispa gave a nod to giving up a stake of the company.
```

Is there any way to exclude those blocks of javascript that starts and ends with the `/*` `*/` before that page is populated with the data. I looked into the API call and there is no way to actually remove it via the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for replacing the content:

```
var regpattern = /(\/\*\s\*\/(.*?)\/\*\s\*\/)/gm

var yourcontent = "include your content here";

yourcontent.replace(regpattern,"");
```

Comment: Thank You! Trying to figure out how to feed this to my `data` im getting from the callback